# Views contextual filters taxonomy name 2 fields using same vocabulary

Tags: 7, views

I have a content where two fields using the same vocabulary.
I want to show nodes related content filtered by the these fields.

I try with relation

**Relationships**

- content:field_1
- (term from field_field_1) Taxonomy term: Content using field1 (Relationship term from field_field_1 ;  Require this relationship )

**Contextual filters**

```
   (field_field_1) Content: field_2

   Provide default value : Taxonomy term id from url
   Load default filter from node page
   Limit terms by vocabulary ( country)

   Specify validation criteria ( taxonomy term )

    Vocabularies : Country
    Filter value type : Term name converted to Term ID
    Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values
```

This query returns nothing.

I don't want to use Views PHP code fields because of security concerns.

Comment: Using php filter will be the easiest way. Whilst I fully agree that php filter is generally a bad thing, I think using in this specific instance is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, out of the box the easiest way is to add a Contextual Filter Content: Has Taxonomy Term Id. This one does not care whether you have 1 field or 20 that reference taxonomy terms.  Further details within are whether you want to match from URL on term id or term name, etc.

I came across your question whilst seeking an answer to mine [How to filter on taxonomy term but only match one field on the node, where two fields (primary and secondary) both use the same vocabulary](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131426/how-to-filter-on-taxonomy-term-but-only-match-one-field-on-the-node-where-two-f) which I think is different.